# Redirect to homepage after submitting e-mail in Forgot password page?

Tags: magento, redirect, passwords, magento-1.7, account

When customer submit his email in Forgot Password page he is redirected to the Login or Create an Account page. How could I redirect users to the Homepage or to the Onepage Checkout page?

Answer (score 0):

The redirect is done in the AccountController.

So basically you could rewrite that controller and especially the forgotPasswordPostAction.

A complete manual how to rewrite a controller can be found on magentocommerce: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_overload_a_controller

Please use this way and do NOT edit the core files itself!